# Problema de codificación en C

Tags: c, struct

me encuentro haciendo un problema y me estaria costando en hacerlo en C. El problema es el siguiente:

**"El código de proyecto está formado por 6 caracteres numéricos, se obtiene invirtiendo la fecha de creación del proyecto. Por ejemplo: si se ingresa la fecha 04/06/14 entonces el código del proyecto será 416040"**

Yo tengo una estructura de tipo fecha

```
struct Tfecha{
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int anio;

};
```

Mi pregunta es: como agruparia esas variables en 1 y lo invertiria?

Trate en convertirlos mediante `cdia = (char) dia`, pero solo me muestra simbolos

************ EDITADO USANDO SPRINTF ****************
Ahora solo el tema es que no me toma el 0 en los formatos, alguna idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int i,j,longitud,dia,mes,anio,aux;
    char agrupa[15];
    dia= 06;
    mes = 04;
    anio = 14;
    sprintf(agrupa, "%d%d%d", dia,mes,anio);
    printf("%s\n", agrupa);

    longitud = strlen(agrupa);
    printf("La longitud es: %d\n", longitud);
    
    for(i=0,j = longitud-1; i < (longitud /2); i++,j--){
        aux = agrupa[i];
        agrupa[i] = agrupa[j];
        agrupa[j]=aux;
    }
    printf("\n la cadena ahora es: %s", agrupa);
```

Comment: Y si es en C, por qué las etiquetas C++ y C#?? Lo otro, ¿has intentado algo para resolver el enunciado?

Comment: Usa `sprintf()`

Comment: @Alfabravo Perdon pense que eran iguales. Trate en convertirlos mediante `cdia = (char) dia`   pero solo me muestra simbolos

Comment: @abulafia Claro pero ese codigo generado lo tengo que guardar en "Codigo de proyecto"

Comment: Pues por eso `sprintf()` te deja el resultado en una cadena que puedes asignar a donde quieras (observa que dije `sprintf()` y no `printf()`)

Comment: @GonzaloIsnardez `cdia = (char) dia` lo que hace es que toma el carácter [ascii](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) equivalente al numero que tu le diste. Si el numero es `65` te dara una `A`. Si quieres imprimir numeros a texto puedes usar `sprintf`. Algo tipo `sprintf(texto, "%02d%02d%02d", f.dia, f.mes, f.anio)`, y luego imprimes el texto al reves.

Comment: @abulafia me re sirvio sus respuestas, lo unico que me va pasando es que me los devuelve sin el 0 ahora edito el post para mostrarles como voy

Comment: @Pablochaches ahora edito el post para mostrar como voy el unico tema es que no me toma el 0 con sprintf

Comment: @GonzaloIsnardez Fijate en el `sprintf` que te puse de ejemplo. En los especificadores de formato le digo que tienen que tener un largo de 2, y que los espacios que sobren lo rellene con `0`s. Eso lo omitiste en el que publicaste

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que una asignación como esta:

```
    dia= 06;
```

no hace lo que supones. No mete un 0 delante del 6. Entre otras cosas porque matemáticamente eso no tendría mucho sentido, ya que los ceros a la izquierda no afectan al valor, que seguiría siendo 6 por muchos ceros que pongas.

Pero es peor que eso, porque en C el 0 a la izquierda sí que tiene un significado, y es que indica que el número está escrito en **base 8**. En el caso del 6 y el 4 eso no afecta al resultado (pues estos números, aún si los interpretas en base 8, siguen siendo el 6 y el 4). Pero si hubieras puesto por ejemplo `09` habrías tenido un error, porque 9 no puede escribirse en base 8 (se escribiría como `011`).

En definitiva, **no pongas ceros** delante de los enteros (a menos que necesites escribirlos en base 8, lo que no es muy habitual).

Por el contrario lo que necesitas es que haya ceos *al convertirlos en cadena*. Es decir, que aunque el número sea 4, al convertirlo en cadena resulte `"04"`. Eso es tan simple como usar adecuadamente la cadena de formato de printf, que debería ser `"%02d"`.

Es decir, tu código debe quedar así:

```
    char agrupa[15];
    dia= 6;
    mes = 4;
    anio = 14;
    sprintf(agrupa, "%02d%02d%02d", dia, mes, anio);
```